# printf formatting doesnt work in perl

Tags: perl

I am using `printf` to format the output. But I am not able to format it properly. Could someone please help me in pointing out what's wrong with the following piece of code?

```
my $sql1 = "select col1,col2,col3 from MYTABLE order by 1";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
$sth->execute(); # or die $DBI::errstr;

my $resultref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();

foreach (@$resultref) {
    print "\n $_->[0] $_->[1] $_->[2] $_->[3]"; # prints 1 row, 3 fields. Fine!
    printf ("%8d %8d %8d ", $_->[0], $_->[1], $_->[2]); # prints 0 for all... why?

  # So i tried the following but still the issue
    my $t1 = $_->[0];
    my $t2 = $_->[1];
    my $t3 = $_->[2];
    my $t4 = $_->[3];

    print "$t1,$t2"; #works
    printf "%8d %8d", $t1, $t2; # doesnt work . why?
}
```

Comment: As usual, `use strict; use warnings;` should be your first defense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys i found the answer.
First of all i used strict and warnings as suggested by tripleee which led me to another error like the following:

***Argument "\x{44}\x{4c}..." isn't numeric in sprintf at main3.pl line 44.***

Later on i first converted the output t string using sprintf and changed %d to %s.

So finally it looked like this:

```
my $string = sprintf ("%22s %18s",$_->[0],$_->[1]); # store it first
print $string;   #Now prints fine
```

Comment: Storing it first should have no bearing on whether or not your output is as expected.  `printf "%22s %18s", $_[0], $_[1];` should suffice.  Didn't it?

Answer (score -1):

No knowing which DBH you are using my guess would be the columns are coming back as strings and Perl doesn't even realize it has a number.  Have you tried something like:
`printf ("%8d %8d %8d ",0+$_->[0], 0+$_->[1], 0+$_->[2]);`

As for why, you can look at Scalar::Utils to ask Perl what it thinks a scalar has in it.  As is the way of an Extension to Perl, the data that shows up in Perl can be rough around the edges.  My guess is Perl would think:
Scalar::Util::isdual($_->[0]) would comeback as false.  But the add 0 trick should coerce it to reevaluate that.

Comment: No i tried it... doesnt help. same output still. Anyways it shouldnt matter whether its string or number.

Comment: I guess I just assumed you were trying to print numbers since you used %8d.  Yes %22s will print a number or a string in that place.

Comment: `%d` will already try to coerce strings to numbers (with a warning if it fails, if you enable warnings)